# Focus on unhidden object

Tags: angular

So, I found the following example of how to focus on an object in Angular.

https://codeburst.io/focusing-on-form-elements-the-angular-way-e9a78725c04f

This, works just fine, as long as the text box has always been visible.  I have tried both with hidden and *ngIf by changing a Boolean variable, and it will always fail to find the object.

Does anyone know what I might have to do differently to set focus after displaying the object?

Thanks

Comment: If you're doing it the `ViewChild` way then ngIf removes the element from the DOM and it sounds like you're just missing a `changeDetectorRef` call to `markForCheck()` or `detectChanges()` after you toggle the visibility bool to get the ref back. Or could always just do the vanilla JS way.

Comment: This ended up being the answer.  I thought detectChanges was places their previously, but it wasn't.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

remember that you need give a breath to Angular to check it is visible or not a input. You give this breath using setTimeout()

Imagine you has  a form like

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="check" 
  (ngModelChange)="check=$event;focus()"
  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
  >Surname visible
  <input formControlName="name">
  <input #surnameControl *ngIf="check" formControlName="surname">

  </form>
```

In your .ts

```
  @ViewChild('surnameControl',{static:false}) control:ElementRef
  focus()
  {
    //outside setTimeout this.control is undefined
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.control.nativeElement.focus()
    })
  }
```

See [a simple example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pr7cz6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)